# Silent Hill 3 Puzzle Unsolvable

Tags: silent-hill-3

I'm currently playing Silent Hill 3 on PS2 in normal difficulty and get stuck in a puzzle. The level is Dark Shopping Mall. I have to get rid of some flying bugs with poisonous chloride gas, which I have to mix with bleach and detergent. The problem is I didn't take the bleach in the women' bathroom early on and now I cannot return there. It is the room with the ladder from ceiling where the door won't open.

Comment: Are there other ways to get bleach? It's not unheard of for games to have unsolvable puzzles if you mess up, but it's extremely rare.

Comment: I went in all possible directions, killed monsters which are pointless to kill and even jumped in a pit, but no bleach was found. However the game is pretty dark so it is possible to oversee some things

Comment: Are you sure you can't return? The bleach is in the otherworld version which should be the version you're currently in. Note there's apparently two women's bathrooms in the Mall. It's not the one you find in the very start.

Comment: @TichomirMitkov In response to the game's darkness, you can usually alter the Brightness setting to make it easier to see.  If the game is still too dark, you can try brightening your TV.

Comment: @BenBrocka I just checked a bathroom - from where the TV is, going through escalator then left and left again. There is the bathroom but it seems useless,as there is no bleach. I'm reading this [Silent Hill 3 Walkthrough](http://www.gamespot.com/features/silent-hill-3-walkthrough-6071913/?page=8). I keep seeking it.

Comment: Read my answer. Because the game is very dark, I hadn't spot the door through which you can return to the bathroom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return to the bathroom in which the bleach is located is in fact possible. After you jump in the room with the ladder from ceiling there is a door in front of you. This door is locked so you must go in the opposite direction. It is hard to spot but there is the door from which you went in to the room earlier. The game will not respawn new monsters so you can walk safely. Search for the bathroom and the bleach is there. There is another bathroom  2 floors above that one which looks more or less the same, but going there is pointless except for hiding from monsters